# BitSet value at a given index value

Tags: java

If I have a `BitSet` in java which has values say `{2,5,9,10,11}`. How do I get the value at the index 2? Or value at a given index.

I tried using `get()` function but it only returns the `boolean` value whether the bit is set or not.

So how can we get a value at a given index like we can in arrays and `ArrayLists` in java.?

Comment: `BitSet` is a set of bits. Bits have 2 values. You can't store `5` into a bitset.

Comment: use hashset instead of bitset or any other set implementations

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the `{2,5,9,10,11}` output. It's displaying which bits are set. There are no values inside the set, just bits that are set (`true`) or not set (`false`).

Answer (score 0):

> So how can we get a value at a given index like we can in arrays and array lists in java.?

You can't ... in the sense that you seem to mean ... without breaking the `BitSet` abstraction.

A `BitSet` is *conceptually* a flexible array of bits or true / false values.  As far as the API is concerned, the "value at a given index" (as you describe it) is either a bit that is set (`get(i)` returns `true`) or unset (`get(i)` returns `true`).

You may be being confused by the output produced by `BitSet::toString`, but that is actually displaying the indexes in the `BitSet` where the bit is set.

Under the hood a `BitSet` is (typically) represented as a `long[]` but you cannot get at that array via the `BitSet` API methods.  (You *could* use nasty reflection to break open the abstraction, but that is a bad idea.  If you need to be able to see the backing array, you are probably better of implementing your own API with either a "leaky abstraction" or with methods that are specific to your application's needs.  Or just do bitwise operations on a `long[]` directly.)